# JSON pagination REST

Tags: android, json, pagination, gson

I have a question on how to get pagination data from a REST server. The server isn't implemented yet, I am working on the client side. I was wondering, is the pagination response always a valid JSON? And if it's not, how it will works from the parsing point of view with GSON and Retrofit2 for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your api call from Android App you just send some params like count and offset, then on backend just select this number from DB beginning from offset value, don't forget to send this value to client.

In your app you can use different techniques like new [Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) which works great with other Architecture Components and RecyclerView. 
Or make your own pagination. The main idea is pretty simple: use recyclerView methods like getLastVisibleItemPosition or etc. to know when you are in the end of your list -> then send new request to your REST using offset number which you got in previous response. And repeat this until you out of items in DB. Take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@etiennelawlor/pagination-with-recyclerview-1cb7e66a502b) example. Good luck

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will dig into that!

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering, is the pagination response always a valid JSON?

Pagination is a way to filter the data you send, json is a format, those are two different things

As long as your json reflects an object, it will be valid. Your json can well be like :

```
{"data" : [{...}, {...}], "page" : 1, "numberResults" : 42}
```